# Google Play Console Developer cuenta comerciante

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console, google-play-console

estoy registrado en Google Play Console Developer para publicar Apps de Android, pero esta sólo permite publicar Apps gratuitas, para venderlar debo configurar mi cuenta "comerciante".

En el formulario me pide datos de empresa y como es de suponer no tengo ninguna.

La pregunta es ¿Cómo hago para registrar una cuenta comerciante para poder vender Apps?.

Comment: Hola Jorny, me parece que esta pregunta no pertenece al sitio Meta, sino al sitio principal de [es.so].

Comment: @Flxtr Stack Overflow no es exclusivo para preguntas de programación (código)?.

Comment: @Jorny: [meta] Es para tratar asuntos sobre el funcionamiento de [es.so]  y algunos otros asuntos relacionados con la la comunidad como los objetivos, encuentros locales. En [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65) se proponen temas para [es.so]. Me parece que la pregunta podría ser bien recibida pues trata sobre un asunto relacionado con la programación, pero no estaría demás revisar "la temática" y si no aparece el tema proponerlo.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de México, existen las figuras de "persona física" y "persona moral", en empresa un residente de México pondría uno u otro, según fuera su caso particular.

En tu país de residencia podría variar el nombre utilizado así como otras cuestiones por lo que lo más apropiado es que consultes con un especialista en temas fiscales de tu país.

Lo anterior debido a que la razón de ser del campo "empresa" en el formulario  son las obligaciones fiscales derivadas del ejercicio de actividades comerciales. Google, como cualquier otra empresa, deberá declarar sus actividades comerciales al país en el que las desarrolla y en muchos casos eso implica proveer información de con quien realiza dichas actividades.